Does the spacetime algebra (STA) formulation of the Dirac equation remove the "double cover" under Lorentz transformations?
As per this section, spacetime algebra allows the Dirac equation to be written entirely in terms of geometric objects, i.e. multivectors.  So I would imagine that these multivectors are invariant objects -- which would imply that, if you transform the Dirac equation to a new reference frame, the multivectors themselves do not change, even though their components do.  Just like any invariant geometric object.
But I have also read that, under the more orthodox complex-matrix-based formulation of the Dirac equation, the spinors in the wavefunction undergo a double cover, in the sense that you must perform two full continuous rotations before the spinor returns to its initial value, and in particular, it picks up a negative sign after a single rotation.
Whereas, if the multivectors in the STA version really are invariant, this latter behavior should not occur, as a given multivector only has one expression relative to a given coordinate frame.  The negative of a multivector is a distinct multivector.  (Not withstanding the fact that, if that multivector is interpreted as a kind of transform and applied to some other object via conjugation, then a multivector and its negative would both effect the same transform.)
Nevertheless, it's conceivable that, even if STA lets us represent the equation using geometric objects, this is merely a representation and the objects employed are NOT invariant, but rather change during transformation such that a full rotation induces a minus sign, just as in the matrix formulation.  So that's my question: are the multivectors in the STA Dirac equation really invariant, such that this formulation no longer exhibits the double-covering under Lorentz transformations?

That cannot be the case, because the double covering is physically meaningful and significant. That is, if the equation does not have entities that double-cover, then it is physically wrong.

In particular, in either of STA or GA, the bivectors themselves go with half-angles, and thus will be picking up the negation when you do one full rotation. It is good that they do so, because otherwise the whole equation would be wrong.

@naturallyInconsistent  Wow, that's interesting -- in that case, do the scalar and pseudoscalar parts together act like a complex number that rotates 180 degrees in the complex plane with each full spatial rotation?  And is there a unified way to describe the type of transformation that the entire even multivector undergoes more generally?

Yes to both. Usually, though, you stop using the directionless complex number representation, and instead use the bivectors, because that captures the full rotation dynamics in N dimension much better.
